# Devise: How to prevent users from seeing other users information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user is logged in he has the ability to see which events he is attending. The action in the **Users Controllers** is the following

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def events
    @title = "Events"
    @event = User.find(params[:id])
    @events = @event.event_presence.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_events'
  end
end
```

However the User(2) is able to see the events of User(3) just by changing the http adress from:
/users/2/events to users/3/events

So my question is, how can I make sure that the User(2) is only able to see the events of User(2) and not of User(3).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter on the current_user.id in your events method instead of params[:id]

```
@event = User.find(current_user.id)
```

However, an even better way would be to have a special route that doesn't include the id

```
get 'events' => 'users#events', as: :users_events
```

and use it like so

```
= link_to 'Events', users_events_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancan is a gem that helps you define what users can and cannot do.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

It works well with devise, so don't worry about implementation.

You can also try The role:

https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role

Personally, I think its documentation is better.